# Bootstrap 3 to 4 migration (Modals stopped appearing)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

We are trying to upgrade our app from Bootstrap 3  to 4, and when we update the library, our exisiting modals no longer appear on the screen.  All of our modals are based on the main example on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ structurewise.

When I click the button to display the modal, in Chrome's debugger I see the show class get added to my .modal element and the html is there, but nothing gets displayed on the screen.  It seems like the modal is loaded but not visible.

Does anyone have any ideas to try?  It's bootstrap  on Angular 1.7, and doesn't work in FF or Chrome, and the modal is structured exactly like the example.  It breaks every modal on our system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be using the fade class on the top level broke it.